# Remove bootstrap auto toggle in collapse accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to disable the auto toggle functionality in bootstrap collapse accordion, when clicking through the links.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div id="exampleAccordion" data-children=".item">
  <div class="item">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#exampleAccordion" href="#exampleAccordion1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="exampleAccordion1">
      Toggle item
    </a>
    <div id="exampleAccordion1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel">
      <p class="mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pretium lorem non vestibulum scelerisque. Proin a vestibulum sem, eget tristique massa. Aliquam lacinia rhoncus nibh quis ornare.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#exampleAccordion" href="#exampleAccordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="exampleAccordion2">
      Toggle item 2
    </a>
    <div id="exampleAccordion2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel">
      <p class="mb-3">
        Donec at ipsum dignissim, rutrum turpis scelerisque, tristique lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus nec dui turpis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `data-parent="#exampleAccordion"` attribute from the `<a>` tag works.